# If $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, can it be shown that $(ax)^2+(by)^2+(cz)^2=1$?

Tags: systems-of-equations

If $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, can it be shown that $(ax)^2+(by)^2+(cz)^2=1$ for all real a, b, c, x, y, z?

Comment: This statement doesn't seem true. Even $(a, b, c) = (0, 0, 1)$ and $(x, y, z) = (1, 0, 0)$ doesn't work.

Comment: You mean, like when all variables are evaluated as $1/\sqrt3$?

Comment: Possibly you meant "for all *suitable* real"?

Comment: Because, based on zwim's logic below, it is possible $\forall t$ when $a = x = 0$, $b = y = cos(t)$, $c = z = sin(t)$. But I can not show, that these are all the values for which the conditions are true.

Answer (score 3):

Even in the reduced case with only two couples of variables $\begin{cases} c=z=0\\a=y=\cos(t)\\b=x=\sin(t)\end{cases}$

Then $(ax)^2+(by)^2+(cz)^2=2\big(\cos(t)\sin(t)\big)^2=\frac 12\sin(2t)^2\le \frac 12\neq 1$

So there are infinity of values for which the equation is not verified.

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $a=c=y=z=0$ and $b=x=1$.